# Omnipay with PayPal express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, omnipay

I'd like to integrate PayPal Express Checkout with Omnipay, but documentation is totally uncompleted. How can I run methods like 'setExpressCheckout', 'doExpressCheckout' and 'getExpressCheckout'? Also, how to redirect all PayPal calls to IPN listener? Does Omnipay provide all these methods or just part of them? Has anyone had chance to use this library with Express Checkout?

Regards!

Comment: I totally agree - Omnipay looks useful but I can't figure out where to start with PayPal Express.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer but first let me recommend that you switch from PayPal Express to PayPal REST as the latter is far better documented and a newer interface.

The actual answer:  Omnipay doesn't work like that.  It doesn't expose the underlying gateway methods directly, and methods like 'setExpressCheckout', 'doExpressCheckout' and 'getExpressCheckout' are PayPal methods not Omnipay methods.  In their place are gateway-independent methods such as purchase() and refund(), etc.

So for an example of the omnipay-paypal REST gateway documentation (as docblocks in the class headers) here is what you do:

```
// Create a gateway for the PayPal RestGateway
// (routes to GatewayFactory::create)
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Rest');

// Initialise the gateway
$gateway->initialize(array(
    'clientId' => 'MyPayPalClientId',
    'secret'   => 'MyPayPalSecret',
    'testMode' => true, // Or false when you are ready for live transactions
));
```

That's just to initialise the gateway.  The process is the same for PayPal express except you use PayPal_Express as the gateway name and you would have different parameters for `initialize()`

Then to make the purchase, e.g. with a card number if you're allowed to do that:

```
// Create a credit card object
// DO NOT USE THESE CARD VALUES -- substitute your own
// see the documentation in the class header.
$card = new CreditCard(array(
            'firstName' => 'Example',
            'lastName' => 'User',
            'number' => '4111111111111111',
            'expiryMonth'           => '01',
            'expiryYear'            => '2020',
            'cvv'                   => '123',
            'billingAddress1'       => '1 Scrubby Creek Road',
            'billingCountry'        => 'AU',
            'billingCity'           => 'Scrubby Creek',
            'billingPostcode'       => '4999',
            'billingState'          => 'QLD',
));

// Do a purchase transaction on the gateway
try {
    $transaction = $gateway->purchase(array(
        'amount'        => '10.00',
        'currency'      => 'AUD',
        'description'   => 'This is a test purchase transaction.',
        'card'          => $card,
    ));
    $response = $transaction->send();
    $data = $response->getData();
    echo "Gateway purchase response data == " . print_r($data, true) . "\n";

    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        echo "Purchase transaction was successful!\n";
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception caught while attempting authorize.\n";
    echo "Exception type == " . get_class($e) . "\n";
    echo "Message == " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Doing a redirect payment such as a PayPal account payment is somewhat different but it's documented in the class docblocks.  See src/Messages/RestPurchaseRequest.php

Comment: Thank you for you post. What's about IPN listener? Does REST don't need it any more? Also, your example above looks like credit/debit card payment, but I need to create express checkout for users which want to pay by creadit/debit cart or just by PayPal account. I think it's something different than you referring to.

Comment: The IPN listener can be created but can't be set on a per-transaction basis like some systems.  You should still be able to use the above code to do non-card payments, just omit the card parameter.  Read through the documentation in the omnipay class headers because that gives detailed examples of how to do this, how to do the handling of the return to your application, and the place where you need to call completePurchase() to confirm that the transaction was successful.